# Fast ndarray processing in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I have a time series of MODIS images, let's say, 30 images. I want to perform a pixel-based linear regression. My idea is:

*the First step, create a np.dstack of images:*

```
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from scipy.stats import linregress

arrays = [] 
for i in listofimages: 
    a,m = GDAL function to read images(i)
    arrays.append(a)
    arrays2 = np.dstack(arrays)`
```

*Second step, create empty arrays for the output results*

```
slope = np.zeros(shape=(arrays2.shape[0],arrays2.shape[1]))
intercept = np.zeros(shape=(arrays2.shape[0],arrays2.shape[1]))
rvalue = np.zeros(shape=(arrays2.shape[0],arrays2.shape[1]))
pvalue = np.zeros(shape=(arrays2.shape[0],arrays2.shape[1]))
```

*The final step is to loop through all rows and columns and perform the linear regression for each array and fill up the empty arrays with regression results*

```
for i in np.arange(0,arrays2.shape[0]):
    for j in np.arange(0,arrays2.shape[1]):
        res = linregress(x,arrays2[i,j,:]) 
        slope[i,j] = res[0]
        intercept[i,j] = res[1]
        rvalue[i,j] = res[2]**2 
        pvalue[i,j] = res[3]
        res = None
```

This procedure surprisingly works, however, it is **too slow**, it took 20minutes on my laptop. Doing the same process to obtain *slope* and *intercept* in QGIS>GRASS>r.series tool is blazingly fast, but it doesn't offer all the flexibility that I want, like for example, polynomial regression or any procedure other than linear regression or simple statistics.

I kind of want to stick it out with my idea and be able to run the process with 100+ images, but I have to implement it in a smarter way. I'm not familiar with multithreading and I believe that it would work.

Comment: What is `linregress`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Multiple Simple Linear Regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646602/python-multiple-simple-linear-regression)